# Python: Read in escaped Unicode characters and turn them into readable text

Tags: python, unicode

I have an RDF file where most objects consist of escaped Unicode characters as follows:

```
...
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Ry%C5%8Dgoku_Kokugikan> <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> "\u4E21\u56FD\u56FD\u6280\u9928"@ja .
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Tunisia> <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> "\u30C1\u30E5\u30CB\u30B8\u30A2"@ja .
...
```

I want to read in this file using a Python script and convert those objects into readable text, i.e. for the above example I would want the following output:

```
両国国技館
チュニジア
```

So far, my code looks as follows:

```
import codecs

for line in codecs.open("labels-en-uris_ja.nt","r","utf-8"):
    tmp = line.split(" ")
    label = tmp[2]
    label = label.split("@")[0]
    label = label.replace("\"","")
    print u"{0}".format(label)
```

However, this returns the escaped Unicode characters unchanged, i.e. as

```
\u4E21\u56FD\u56FD\u6280\u9928
\u30C1\u30E5\u30CB\u30B8\u30A2
```

Using simply `print label` in the last line of my code gives exactly the same result. However, `print u"\u4E21\u56FD\u56FD\u6280\u9928"` gives the desired output, so I assume there is something wrong with the way I read in that file. What would be the correct way to produce the output I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `.decode("unicode_escape")` function on your string object to do this.

```
print u"{0}".format(label.decode("unicode_escape"))
```